# Problem with interpolation

Tags: interpolation

I have a problem with the function interpolation. when I use it my points are all very shifted. Do you have an idea of the solution?

```
data = Import["EQE.txt", "Table", "HeaderLines" -> 3];
eqelambda = Table[{data[[n, 1]], data[[n, 5]]}, {n, Length[data[[All, 1]]]}];

h[x_] := hplanck*c/(x*10^-9)
f[x_] := Log[-Log[1 - x]]

data11 = h /@ eqelambda[[All, 1]];
data12 = f /@ eqelambda[[All, 2]];
data1 = Table[{data11[[n]], data12[[n]]}, {n, Length[data11]}];
intdata1 = Interpolation[data1];
ListPlot[data1]
Plot[intdata1[x], {x, 0, 1.8}]
```

Data files here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4ztzyv4zjwwlh1y/u1P_ELgBVA

Comment: ...and where are `data11` and `data12`?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the external link to the data files is broken, and the question is unanswerable without it.

Answer (score 2):

We can't find your problem since your question lacks your data definition. But perhaps a working example of what *I think* you're trying to do may be useful:

```
datal1 = Range@8;
datal2 = Range@8^2;
data1 = Transpose[{datal1, datal2}];
intdata1 = Interpolation[data1];
Show[ListPlot@data1, Plot[intdata1[x], {x, 1, 8}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I wanted to add my graphs to this question but I wasn't able to share it. Here are thoses graph and the origin of my datas.
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/4ztzyv4zjwwlh1y/u1P_ELgBVA)

And that's the begining of my program:

data = Import["EQE.txt", "Table", "HeaderLines" -> 3];
eqelambda = 
  Table[{data[[n, 1]], data[[n, 5]]}, {n, Length[data[[All, 1]]]}];
h[x_] := hplanck*c/(x*10^-9)
f[x_] := Log[-Log[1 - x]]
data11 = h /@ eqelambda[[All, 1]];
data12 = f /@ eqelambda[[All, 2]];
...